# How to do a running count of dates within a date range in excel?

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to build a formula in excel, that will do a running count of dates within a specified date range for an item. For example: Item A has a Start Date of 7/15 and an End Date of 7/18. I need a formula that will "tally" or add "1" to a running count for 7/15, 7/16, 7/17, 7/18 in another column that has a comprehensive list of dates. How can I do this?

[EXAMPLE ATTACHED AS LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8hJc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Some examples would be helpful, but it sounds like you're looking for [`countifs`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

If we create two excel tables, one called `Items` with `Start` and `End` dates:

```
Title   Start   End
ItemA   7/15/2017   7/18/2017
ItemB   7/16/2017   7/20/2017
```

And one called `Dates` which counts the `Items`

```
Date    Count
7/15/2017   1
7/16/2017   2
7/17/2017   2
7/18/2017   2
7/19/2017   1
7/20/2017   1
```

Then our formula in the `Count` column of `Dates` would be

`=COUNTIFS(Items[Start],"<="&[@Date],Items[End],">="&[@Date])`

In plain english, this is saying "Count all items in Table `Items` where the value in the `Start` column is less than or equal to the value in my `Date` column and the `End` column is greater than or equal to the value in my `Date` column. Note that these formulas are entirely in [Excel Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) format, which makes for more readable formulas. If we want `A1` notation, we will assume that the `Items` table starts at `A1`, which would result in the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$3,"<="&$E2,$C$2:$C$3,">="&$E2)`

[image]

Comment: Stephen, this is exactly what I am looking for (on the right track), however there is an added complexity where I have a Pivot Table deriving these start and end dates along with the App Items. Also broken out by LINUX and SOLARIS. I have attached an example where I need to calculate a running count of those two categories based on the pivot table to the right.

Comment: Actually I ended up figuring out how to split it by LINUX and SOLARIS with two separate pivot tables. But your formula for each part worked! THANK YOU!